# ClassNotFoundException deploy on Weblogic

Tags: maven, weblogic, weblogic12c

I always get the following Error when I am trying to redeploy an EAR on a weblogic 12c cluster with Jenkins and maven:

```
Target state: redeploy failed on Cluster xxx
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException
```

I already added `<wls:package-name>javax.xml.*</wls:package-name>` in the `weblogic-application.xml`file.
The problem started after adding this dependency in maven:

```
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.17</version>
```

Does anyone have an idea for solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Before I had

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>javax.xml.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

And i changed to this:

```
<wls:prefer-application-resources>
    <wls:resource-name>javax.xml.*</wls:resource-name>
</wls:prefer-application-resources>
```

Now it works. Can anyone explain the exact difference between `prefer-application-packages`and `prefer-application-resources`? The description in official documentation does not really help me.